# Show that $\Phi$ is negation complete.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Im working on a FOL exercise but i'm a little stuck here. Let $S$ be a symbol set and $\mathcal{J} = (\mathcal{U}, \beta)$ an $S$-interpretation. Further let $\Phi:=\{\varphi\in L^{S}|\mathcal{J}\models\varphi$}

Show that $\Phi$ is negation complete.

So i have to show that $\Phi\vdash \varphi$ or $\Phi\vdash\neg\varphi$ But i don't know where to start. Please help.

Comment: It is enough to show that for each sentence $\varphi$ of $L^S$, either $\varphi \in \Phi$ or $\neg \varphi \in \Phi$. In order to do this, you may use the fact that from the definition of an interpretation $\mathcal{J}$, it follows that either $\mathcal{J} \models \varphi$ or $\mathcal{J} \models \neg \varphi$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.